# Multiple duplicates load into GridView from SD card

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-mediaplayer, android-gridview

I am trying to load `Uri` sound files from my SD card into a custom `GridView` where each item contains an `ImageView` (for the `Uri`) and a `TextView` for the sound file title, but it keeps loading duplicates. I have 6 sound files on my card, but it loads 12, then very oddly another 3 after all the drawables load. The drawables (placeholder images) load fine, they load the right number.

I put a lot of the file I/O into an `AsyncTask`, but I doubt this would cause any problems like this.

When I log everything, I see things getting unexpectedly loaded a few times (console below), including odd null values. I have other working code with the exact same process, except loading images instead of sound files, and it works perfectly, so this is really puzzling. I realize loading `Uri`s into a `GridView` is not ideal, as there is nothing to see in the `ImageView`, but when I click on each item, it does play the file, so that part is correct. I will rework the image problem later.

Any idea why things are loading so strangely in duplicates? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

It turns out since I had the `ArrayList<AudioGridItem>` in my adapter constructor, that any change to my list was automatically updating, so I didn't need to add it again to the adapter manually. So I just deleted the adding to adapter in my `onPostExecute()` and it worked!

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(AudioGridItem result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            // add the default icons remaining, to GridView, if less than 15 files on SD card
            for (int i = 0; i < (15 - numberSDCardFiles.length); i++) {
                audioAdapter.add(drawable);
            }

            audioAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

[image]

**AudioTab.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection.audiotab;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/8/15.
 */
public class AudioTab extends Fragment {

    private GridView gridView;
    private GridViewAudioAdapter audioAdapter;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private String[] numberSDCardFiles = null;
    File[] files;
    ArrayList<AudioGridItem> audioFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    MediaPlayer mp;
    AudioGridItem audioGridItem;
    AudioGridItem drawable;

    public AudioTab(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.audio_tab, container, false);

        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        // instantiate your progress dialog
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

        // with fragments, make sure you include the rootView when finding id
        gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.audio_grid);
        // Create the Custom Adapter Object
        audioAdapter = new GridViewAudioAdapter(getActivity(), audioFiles);
        // Set the Adapter to GridView
        gridView.setAdapter(audioAdapter);

        Log.d("TAG", "Items in audioAdapter1: " + audioAdapter.getCount());

        if(audioAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
            // load contents of SD card through AsyncTask
            new AudioDownloaderTask().execute();
        }

        setupGridViewListener();

        return v;
    }

    private class AudioDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, AudioGridItem> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading cute collection ...");
            //set the progress bar to cancelable on back button
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected AudioGridItem doInBackground(Object... params) {

            retrieveAudio();

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(AudioGridItem result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Log.d("TAG", "Items in audioFiles: " + audioFiles.size());

            // Add whole ArrayList to adapter
            audioAdapter.addAll(audioFiles);

            Log.d("TAG", "Number of item in audioAdapter2: " + audioAdapter.getCount());

            // add the default icons remaining, to GridView, if less than 15 files on SD card
            for (int i = 0; i < (15 - numberSDCardFiles.length); i++) {
                audioAdapter.add(drawable);
            }

            audioAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d("TAG", "Number of item in audioAdapter3: " + audioAdapter.getCount());
            Log.d("TAG", "Number of items in SD Card files: " +numberSDCardFiles.length);
        }
    }

    public void retrieveAudio() {

        try {
            // gets directory Cute Videos from sd card
            File cuteVideosDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                    (Environment.DIRECTORY_PODCASTS), "Cute Sounds");

            // puts list into files Array
            files = cuteVideosDir.listFiles();

            // get number of files in Cute Sounds directory
            numberSDCardFiles =  new String[files.length];

            for (File singleFile : files) {
                // get both audio file and audio title
                Uri audioUri = Uri.fromFile(singleFile);
                String audioTitle = singleFile.getName();

                audioGridItem = new AudioGridItem(audioUri, audioTitle);

                // add Uri and title to ArrayList
                audioFiles.add(audioGridItem);
            }

            // changes drawable into an AudioGridItem object (Uri, but no String)
            drawable = new AudioGridItem(Uri.parse("android.resource://org.azurespot/"
                                + R.drawable.ic_sounds_placeholder), null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setupGridViewListener() {
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                                    View item, int pos, long id) {

                if(!(audioAdapter.getItem(pos).equals(drawable))) {

                    Uri soundFile = (audioAdapter.getItem(pos)).getAudio();

                    try {
                        mp.setDataSource(getActivity(), soundFile);
                        mp.prepare();
                        mp.start();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

**GridViewAudioAdapter.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection.audiotab;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.azurespot.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/8/15.
 */
public class GridViewAudioAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AudioGridItem> {

    private TextView audioTitleView;
    int position;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    public GridViewAudioAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AudioGridItem> audio) {
        super(context, 0, audio);

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View itemView, ViewGroup parent) {

        this.position = position;

        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.audio_tab_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.audioView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.audio_icon);
            audioTitleView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.audio_title);

            // stores holder with view
            itemView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder)itemView.getTag();
        }

        // get position of the item clicked in GridView
        final AudioGridItem audioGridItem = getItem(position);

        if (audioGridItem != null) {
            Uri audioUri = audioGridItem.getAudio();
            String audioTitle = audioGridItem.getAudioTitle();
            String rootName = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(audioTitle);

            Log.d("TAG", "Value of audioTitle: " + audioTitle);

            Log.d("TAG", "Value of rootName: " + rootName);

            // set the photos into the ImageView slots
            holder.audioView.setImageURI(audioUri);
            audioTitleView.setText(rootName);

            // positioning the image in the GridView slot
            holder.audioView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            holder.audioView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                    (250, 250));
        }

        return itemView;

    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        ImageView audioView;
    }
}
```

**Here is my model: AudioGridItem.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection.audiotab;

import android.net.Uri;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 4/26/15.
 */
public class AudioGridItem {

    private Uri audio;
    private String audioTitle;

    public AudioGridItem(Uri audio, String autoTitle) {
        super();
        this.audio = audio;
        this.audioTitle = autoTitle;
    }

    public Uri getAudio() {

        return audio;
    }

    public void setAudio(Uri audio){

        this.audio = audio;
    }

    public String getAudioTitle(){

        return audioTitle;
    }

    public void setAudioTitle(String audioTitle){

        this.audioTitle = audioTitle;

    }

}
```

**Logs**

```
04-27 16:46:56.406  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-27 17:04:28.176  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-27 17:04:28.326  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Items in audioAdapter1: 0
04-27 17:04:28.376  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound54.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.376  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound54
04-27 17:04:28.386  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound54.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.386  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound54
04-27 17:04:28.446  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound54.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.446  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound54
04-27 17:04:28.446  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound54.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.446  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound54
04-27 17:04:28.466  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound54.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.466  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound54
04-27 17:04:28.466  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound66.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.466  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound66
04-27 17:04:28.476  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound19.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.476  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound19
04-27 17:04:28.476  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound47.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.486  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound47
04-27 17:04:28.486  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound49.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.486  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound49
04-27 17:04:28.486  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound51.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.486  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound51
04-27 17:04:28.606  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Items in audioFiles: 6
04-27 17:04:28.606  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Number of item in audioAdapter2: 12
04-27 17:04:28.606  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Number of item in audioAdapter3: 21
04-27 17:04:28.606  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Number of items in SD Card files: 6
04-27 17:04:28.616  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound54.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.616  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound54
04-27 17:04:28.616  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound54.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.616  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound54
04-27 17:04:28.616  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound54.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.616  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound54
04-27 17:04:28.616  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound54.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.616  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound54
04-27 17:04:28.626  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound54.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.626  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound54
04-27 17:04:28.626  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound66.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.626  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound66
04-27 17:04:28.626  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound19.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.626  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound19
04-27 17:04:28.626  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound47.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.636  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound47
04-27 17:04:28.636  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound49.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.636  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound49
04-27 17:04:28.636  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound51.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.636  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound51
04-27 17:04:28.636  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound54.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.636  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound54
04-27 17:04:28.636  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound66.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.636  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound66
04-27 17:04:28.646  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound19.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.646  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound19
04-27 17:04:28.646  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound47.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.646  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound47
04-27 17:04:28.646  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound49.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.646  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound49
04-27 17:04:28.656  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound51.3gpp
04-27 17:04:28.656  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound51
04-27 17:04:28.656  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: null
04-27 17:04:28.656  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: null
04-27 17:04:28.666  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: null
04-27 17:04:28.666  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: null
04-27 17:04:28.666  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: null
04-27 17:04:28.666  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: null
04-27 17:04:29.876  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-27 17:04:30.516  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: null
04-27 17:04:30.516  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: null
04-27 17:04:30.516  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: null
04-27 17:04:30.516  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: null
04-27 17:04:30.516  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: null
04-27 17:04:30.516  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: null
04-27 17:04:31.696  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound54.3gpp
04-27 17:04:31.696  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound54
04-27 17:04:31.696  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound66.3gpp
04-27 17:04:31.696  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound66
04-27 17:04:31.696  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of audioTitle: Sound19.3gpp
04-27 17:04:31.696  24668-24668/org.azurespot D/TAG﹕ Value of rootName: Sound19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out

```
 audioAdapter = new GridViewAudioAdapter(getActivity(), audioFiles);
```

the above line `audioFiles` is an empty `ArrayList`and your `audioAdapter` is looking to it as his backup man.. Now in your `retrieveAudio()` method you add items to `audioFiles` like this `audioFiles.add(audioGridItem);` now `audioFiles` contains 1 item, -(suppose that is the only item you add) but in your `onPostExecute` you call do this

```
Log.d("TAG", "Items in audioFiles: " + audioFiles.size());
// Add whole ArrayList to adapter
audioAdapter.addAll(audioFiles);  //pay attention here
Log.d("TAG", "Number of item in audioAdapter2: " + audioAdapter.getCount());
```

you have now added `audioFiles` to `audioFiles` giving you a total of two items in your `GridView` from the documentation [addAll(collection)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20T%3E%29)  *Adds the specified Collection at the end of the array* which means it does not replace it, so what you got to do is forget about the `onPostExecute` adding and use on `onProgressUpdate` to add the item one by one and call `notifyDatasetChanged()` because you can't call it in the doInBackground

Comment: Thanks Elitz, but when you say I add `audioFiles` to `audioFiles`, I don't see how, since I am adding`audioFiles` objects to the `audioAdapter` that has an empty `ArrayList`... how is it that 2 copies get added? (Maybe explain further, thanks).

Comment: what i mean is your gridview is pointing to `audioFiles` as its data source, and in your `retrieveAudio()` method in your doinbackground you add items to this `audioFiles` which means if you add 10 items to it, your gridview will show 10 items, so now you have 10 items, then you in your `postExecute` you add items to the 10 items that are pointing to or have reference to `audioFiles` in the adapter, and by  the addAll definition it does not replace the `audioFiles` but it adds the items at the end of `audioFiles`. @NoniA.

Comment: _continuation_  -  so you have have added 10 more items to `audioFiles` and those 10 more items are `audioFiles` which is a dupe of `audioFiles` therefore you have added `audioFiles` to `audioFiles` , get me? do you want me to re-write the solution code for you? @NoniA.

Comment: Oh thanks, that is so weird though, because this code works for my other 2 classes where I add photo and video. But I just eliminated the add in `onPostExecute` and it worked! If only I would have logged right before the adding. I assumed nothing had changed, but I see your point now, since `audioAdapter` is a reference to the adapter with the `ArrayList` already in its constructor, it gets updated when new items are added, on its own. Thank you so much! I was stuck for 2 days on this. :)